# Unable to load Chart.js data from getJSON / PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, chart.js

I am trying to add chart data from `PHP` file.
Chart is drawn when I add the values manually - `data: [28,20,2,7]`,
But chart doesn't appear, when I add the data from `PHP` file.

Where am I going wrong here?
How can I add these values from PHP output?

My `PHP` code:

```
echo json_encode(array($rectotals,$recX,$recXS,$recXM));
```

Php file output (this looks OK):

```
[28,20,2,7]
```

Here is how i get the data:

```
$.getJSON("chartdata.php").then(function(chart_data1){
        alert(chart_data1);
    })
```

Alert result (This is also OK):

```
localhost:63342 says 28,20,2,7
```

My chartjs script:

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="340"></canvas>
<script>

    $.getJSON("chartdata.php").then(function(chart_data){
        alert(chart_data);
    })

    //setTimeout(function() { alert(db_data1); }, 2000);

    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
            labels: ['Total', 'Size X', 'Size XS', 'Size SM],
            datasets: [{

                data: chart_data,
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgb(255,99,132)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
                    'rgb(255,206,86)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                    'rgb(255,159,64)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 0.5,
            }]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            animation: {
                duration: 2800,
                easing: 'easeInOutQuad',
            },
            layout: {
                padding: {
                    left: 0,
                    right: 0,
                    top: 15,
                    bottom: 0
                }
            },
            cutoutPercentage : 75,
            legend: {
                display: false,
                position: 'bottom',
                fullWidth: true,
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
let myChart = null;

function getConfig(chart_data){
  return ({
    type: "pie",
    data: {
      labels: ["Total", "Size X", "Size XS", "Size SM"],
      datasets: [
        {
          data: chart_data,
          backgroundColor: [
            "rgb(54,162,235)",
            "rgb(255,99,132)",
            "rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)",
            "rgb(255,192,33)"
          ],
          borderColor: [
            "rgb(255,255,255)",
            "rgb(255,255,255)",
            "rgb(255,255,255)",
            "rgb(255,255,255)"
          ],
          hoverBackgroundColor: ['#373739', '#373739', '#373739', '#373739'],
        }
      ]
    },
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      animation: {
        duration: 0, //2800, I remove animation time
        easing: "easeInOutQuad"
      },
      tooltips: {
        mode: 'nearest'
      },
      layout: {
        padding: {
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          top: 15,
          bottom: 0
        }
      },
      cutoutPercentage: 66,
      legend: {
        display: false,
        position: "bottom",
        fullWidth: true
      }
    }
  });
}

function getJSON(){
    // emulate fetch
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const chart_data = [
      Math.random() * 50,
      Math.random() * 50,
      Math.random() * 50,
      Math.random() * 50
    ];
    resolve(chart_data)
  })
}

function update(){
  getJSON().then(data => {
      myChart.data.datasets[0].data = data;
      myChart.update();
  });
}

function initializeChart() {
    getJSON().then(data => { 
        myChart = new Chart(ctx, getConfig(data));
    });
}

initializeChart();
document.getElementById('update_chart').addEventListener('click', update, false);
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <button id="update_chart">Update Records</button>
    </div>
    <canvas id="myChart" width="50" height="40"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Daniil, I am testing your example. 

Chart redraws with the new values each time record is updated,  But doesn't seem chart itself is updated. 

On hover chart shows its label + values, 
Noticed that each time chart redraws, 
On hover, Value toggles between old value & new value
Chart itself wobbles showing old value & new value.

this only stops, when I reload/refresh the page
Probably need to use .update(); for the chart.
I am unable to figure out where or how to use it.
Pls help

Comment: I used `setInterval` to change data every `1000 milliseconds` you can remove it and left just `getJSON().then(data => drawChart(data));` or even `drawChart(data)`

Comment: Thank you Daniil, i am able to update data and redraw the chart with your code, But when i move my cursor over the chart, see what happens, how can i resolve it: https://jsfiddle.net/hakxonk/eo0qrkja/32/

Comment: Hi @HassanKhaleel. Yes, I see now. I'm sorry it's my bad. I fixed my answer. Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

`Query.getJSON()` makes an asynchronous `HTTP` request. Once the result arrives, the chart has already been created and the obtained data has no effect on the chart.

To solve this, place the chart creation inside the `then` callback as follows.

```
$.getJSON("chartdata.php").then(function(chart_data) {
  var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    ...
});
```