# Send value from index.php to apex chart .js file

Tags: javascript, php, apexcharts

The following is the "dashbaord.js" file in a admin dashboard script.
I want to transfer data from my index.php to display different Apex chart data
instead of the "series1", "series2" and the "categories" I want to send custom values. How can I do that ?
I can manage php, but I know nothing about javascript.
I tried to put <?php.. inside the .js file and it didnt work.

```
// currently sale
var options = {
    series: [{
        name: 'series1',
        data: [6, 20, 15, 40, 18, 20, 18, 23, 18, 35, 30, 55, 0]
    }, {
        name: 'series2',
        data: [2, 22, 35, 32, 40, 25, 50, 38, 42, 28, 20, 45, 0]
    }],
    chart: {
        height: 240,
        type: 'area',
        toolbar: {
            show: false
        },
    },
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
    },
    stroke: {
        curve: 'smooth'
    },
    xaxis: {
        type: 'category',
        low: 0,
        offsetX: 0,
        offsetY: 0,
        show: false,
        categories: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan"],
        labels: {
            low: 0,
            offsetX: 0,
            show: false,
        },
        axisBorder: {
            low: 0,
            offsetX: 0,
            show: false,
        },
    },
    markers: {
        strokeWidth: 3,
        colors: "#ffffff",
        strokeColors: [ CubaAdminConfig.primary , CubaAdminConfig.secondary ],
        hover: {
            size: 6,
        }
    },
    yaxis: {
        low: 0,
        offsetX: 0,
        offsetY: 0,
        show: false,
        labels: {
            low: 0,
            offsetX: 0,
            show: false,
        },
        axisBorder: {
            low: 0,
            offsetX: 0,
            show: false,
        },
    },
    grid: {
        show: false,
        padding: {
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            bottom: -15,
            top: -40
        }
    },
    colors: [ CubaAdminConfig.primary , CubaAdminConfig.secondary ],
    fill: {
        type: 'gradient',
        gradient: {
            shadeIntensity: 1,
            opacityFrom: 0.7,
            opacityTo: 0.5,
            stops: [0, 80, 100]
        }
    },
    legend: {
        show: false,
    },
    tooltip: {
        x: {
            format: 'MM'
        },
    },
};

var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart-currently"), options);
chart.render();
```

Comment: this is example for js: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65420671/unable-to-load-chart-js-data-from-getjson-php/65421898#65421898

Comment: can you apply full html page (only chart and options without unnecessary details) witch you get from php? also errors from console if they exist